# Surrounding AVCaptureDeviceInput within a do block

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm currently following along a tutorial which shows how to use the `AVFoundation` framework to create a custom camera view.

I'm having a bit of confusion when trying to instantiate an instance of `AVCaptureDeviceInput`.

I have the following:

```
var error: NSError?

        do  {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
            if error == nil && captureSession!.canAddInput(input) {
                captureSession!.addInput(input)
            }
        } catch error {
            // Handle errors
        } catch {
            // Catch other errors
        }
```

The error I am faced with is:

> Argument type 'NSError' does not conform to expected tpye '_ErrorCodeProtocol'

To fix this, I added the following to the catch:

```
catch error as! NSError
```

This fixing the compile error, but by doing this wouldn't I be re-assiging the error variable which would therefore make the if check pointless?

I'm relatively new to the Swift programming language, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, you usually have no need to declare `error` variables when using `do-try-catch`. You can `catch` the error, using the `case-let` like syntax:

```
//### Usually, no need to declare `error`.
do  {
    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
    //### When error occures, the rest of the code in do-catch will not be executed, you have no need to check `error`.
    if captureSession!.canAddInput(input) {
        captureSession!.addInput(input)
    }
} catch let error as Error {
    // Handle all errors
    print(error)
    //...
} //### The `catch` above catches all errors, no need to put another `catch`
```

Swift automatically assumes `let error as Error` when you omit some parts of the `catch` clause, so writing the line as `} catch let error {` or just `} catch {` is equivalent.

Comment: Oh right, thank you for your explanation. Makes a lot more sense. Thanks :)